# Loop problem - Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy

I think that I have a problem with the loop on my taxonomy page. On any part of the code (specially on the sidebar) that I need the permalink, it always return the link of the first item of the taxonomy loop, but the correct, is of the current page.

This is my taxonomy page code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="header_titulo">
    <div class="container">
        <?php $term_global = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy')); ?>
        <h1 class="esquerda"><a title="Voltar" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . '/colecoes'; ?>">< Voltar</a></h1>
        <h1 class="direita_voltar"><?php echo $term_global->name; ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hr"></div>
</div>
<div id="content-container" class="center">
    <div class="sidebar esquerda">
        <?php if (have_posts()){ ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()){ ?>
                <?php the_post(); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php get_sidebar('colecoes'); ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="direita">
        <?php
            $args = array('post_type' => 'colecoes',  'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'order' => 'DESC', 'taxonomy' => 'categorias', 'term' => $term_global->slug);
            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
            $contagem = 0;
            if (sizeof($loop->posts) >= 1){
            echo "<ul class='listagem'>";
                while ($loop->have_posts()){ 

                    $loop->the_post();
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'numberposts' => null,
                        'post_status' => null,
                        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                        'numberposts' => 1
                    );
                    $attachments = get_posts($args);
                    if ($contagem == 2 || $contagem == 5 || $contagem == 8 || $contagem == 11 || $contagem == 14){
                        echo "<li class='sem_borda'>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<li>";
                    }
                    if ($attachments) {
                        echo '<a class="imagem" href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/colecao/' . $loop->post->post_name . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">';
                            echo '<div class="fotos">';
                                the_thumb(get_the_title(),0,1,false);
                                the_thumb(get_the_title(),1,2,false);
                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</a>';
                    }
                    echo '<div class="box">';
                        echo '<p><a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/colecao/' . $loop->post->post_name . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo "</li>";
                    if ($contagem == 2 || $contagem == 5 || $contagem == 8){
                        echo '<div class="hr colecao"></div>';
                    }

                    $contagem = $contagem + 1;
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }else{
                echo category_description(); 
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="direita">
        <div class="paginacao">
            <?php wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $loop)); ?>
            <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to build the permalinks yourself? That looks really tricky and fragile.

Also, you're getting a little confused trying to deal with the `$loop` WP_Query object. When you call `$loop->the_post();`, what you're doing is populating the global variable **$post** with the next post in the **$loop** query object. So everywhere that you're iterating over `$loop->post`, you could actually just write `$post`.

So, for example, replace this code:

```
<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/colecao/' . $loop->post->post_name . '"
```

with something that uses WordPress's permalink functions, like

```
<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '"
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test your code, but I would check first the follow functions,

`<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>`

before you call your sidebar. I don't think you need both of them.

Comment: Hello Daniel. I tried with only one and both. The rusult is the same =/

Comment: Did you try to comment all your <?php rewind_posts(); ?> <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> on the code?

Comment: `rewind_posts()` resets the pointer to the first post in the current query. `wp_reset_query()` resets the query to be the main query on the page. So if you wanted to do something with the posts in the main query after iterating over your $loop query, you might call wp_reset_query(). I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it.